# Connect to MongoDB without password using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm a bit confused with the problem with pymongo and MongoDB.

I have a MongoDB server that I can connect using Studio 3T without any password (behind VPN):
[image]
[image]

```
mongodb://mongodb-dev.my.server:27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000
```

When I'm connecting to the server from Python I get error:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: Could not reach any servers in [('mongodb-dev', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames or IPs?, Timeout: 5.0s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6200d97072f39326314e6916, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb-dev', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb-dev:27017: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Python script:

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://mongodb-dev.my.server:27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000')

db = client.get_database('feeeper')
col = db.get_collection('my_collection')

cur = col.find({}, {'body': 1})
last_task = cur.sort([('created', pymongo.DESCENDING)]).limit(1)

for t in last_task:
    print(t)
```

UPD:
Ping to the server works fine:
[image]

I can connect to the server with mongo shell:
[image]

Comment: Did you actually try to do anything in Studio 3T? Try a read operation to ensure the connection is complete.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole Yes, everything works just fine.

Comment: My next step is 1. Ensure I can ping the server 2. Try and connect with the mongo shell. These two steps often resolve any problems. Can you login to the server and try connecting via local host?

Comment: It looks like the server is configured as a replicaset. Can you click the "To URL" button and post the results.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole I've updated the question: ping works, mongo shell connects

Comment: @BellyBuster The address at python script is already from "To URL" window. On other hand on left pane (with servers) I see that: `xxxxx.xx.local [replica set: develop] [direct]`

Comment: Can you test with the IP address rather than the DNS name in the mongoclient?

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole mongo shell works fine, studio 3t connects correctly, python script fails same as with dns name

Comment: Is it actually a DNS name or are you using some form of local /etc/hosts file or similar? I see you are obscuring the names in the shell and ping examples which leads me to believe the URLs are different from the unobscured url in 3t, mongodb-dev..my.server

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole yes, this is DNS name (behind vpn if I can say so). My hosts doesn't have any records for the address. You are right I'be changed urls for the screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with default arguments for `MongoClinet` constructor. The constructor has parameter `directConnection` with default value `False` — connect to replica set:

> directConnection (optional): if True, forces this client to
> connect directly to the specified MongoDB host as a standalone. If false, the client connects to the entire replica set of which the given MongoDB host(s) is a part. If this is True and a mongodb+srv:// URI or a URI containing multiple seeds is provided, an exception will be raised.

When I've set `directConnection` as `True` the query worked fine.